# Generating UNIQUE Random Numbers within a range

Tags: php

I need to generate random UNIQUE numbers within a range, how can I do that? I can generate random number by

```
generator:
$arr = [];
$x = rand($min, $max);
$len = count($arr);
$flag = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++)
{
 if ($flag === 1)
   goto generator;
 if ($x === $arr[$i])
   $flag = 1;
}
$arr[$index] = $x;
$index++; 
goto generator;
```

I know this code is bad, so I need a better optimized code of my version !
help !

example:
if i need to generate 3 numbers within 1 to 15 they should be like 5, 9, 1 but not 3,1,2 [with in 1 - 3 (numbers i want to generate) ]

Comment: Unique random number? "Unique number" and "random number" cannot coexist. Think about it. You can have unique. Or you can have random. Which do you want?

Comment: i want random number and store it in array, all the number in the array must be unique

Comment: Are those `goto` statements? I feel like I'm reading `TI-BASIC`...

Comment: yup, PHP still support it :P for lazy guys like me

Comment: @Soulav I updated my answer, you might be interested to give it a read.

Comment: @Sourav Actually, PHP only recently introduced `goto` in version 5.3.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Array with range of numbers at random order:

```
$numbers = range(1, 20);
shuffle($numbers);
```

Wrapped function:

```
function UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
}
```

Example:

```
<?php
print_r( UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(0,25,5) );
?>
```

Result:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => 14
    [1] => 16
    [2] => 17
    [3] => 20
    [4] => 1
)
```

Comment: This will include *all* numbers within that range, not random ones.

Comment: If you only need 5 random numbers, just pick the first 5 items in the array.

Comment: Good point. Make it into a function and submit it to be included into the massive PHP function database ;)

Comment: if i try to generate 3 number with your function they are like 1, 3, 2 but i want something like 1, 5, 15 [if limit is 1-15 ]

Comment: Huh? `UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(1,15,3)` perfectly returns `( [0] => 13 [1] => 20 [2] => 15 )`.

Comment: Not a good choice if you want high random numbers. Think how long does it take for this function to generate 30 rand numbers between 1 and 50k. It will first create an array with 50 thousand integers, then will try and shuffle each and every one of them, and then will start slicing from another 50 thousand.

Comment: In PHP 7.1, shuffle() is the culprit here. Not array_slice() or range().

Answer (score 19):

```
$len = 10;   // total number of numbers
$min = 100;  // minimum
$max = 999;  // maximum
$range = []; // initialize array
foreach (range(0, $len - 1) as $i) {
    while(in_array($num = mt_rand($min, $max), $range));
    $range[] = $num;
}
print_r($range);
```

---

I was interested to see how the accepted answer stacks up against mine. It's useful to note, a hybrid of both may be advantageous; in fact a function that conditionally uses one or the other depending on certain values:

```
# The accepted answer
function randRange1($min, $max, $count)
{
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $count);
}

# My answer
function randRange2($min, $max, $count)
{
    $i = 0;
    $range = array();
    while ($i++ < $count) {
        while(in_array($num = mt_rand($min, $max), $range));
        $range[] = $num;
    }
    return $range;
}

echo 'randRange1: small range, high count' . PHP_EOL;
$time = microtime(true);
randRange1(0, 9999, 5000);
echo (microtime(true) - $time) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

echo 'randRange2: small range, high count' . PHP_EOL;
$time = microtime(true);
randRange2(0, 9999, 5000);
echo (microtime(true) - $time) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

echo 'randRange1: high range, small count' . PHP_EOL;
$time = microtime(true);
randRange1(0, 999999, 6);
echo (microtime(true) - $time) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

echo 'randRange2: high range, small count' . PHP_EOL;
$time = microtime(true);
randRange2(0, 999999, 6);
echo (microtime(true) - $time) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
```

The results:

```
randRange1: small range, high count
0.019910097122192

randRange2: small range, high count
1.5043621063232

randRange1: high range, small count
2.4722430706024

randRange2: high range, small count
0.0001051425933837
```

If you're using a smaller range and a higher count of returned values, the accepted answer is certainly optimal; however as I had expected, larger ranges and smaller counts will take much longer with the accepted answer, as it must store every possible value in range. You even run the risk of blowing PHP's memory cap. A hybrid that evaluates the ratio between range and count, and conditionally chooses the generator would be the best of both worlds.

Comment: i really appreciate your code, it executes muchhhh faster than the selected ans, but fails for a little range [1-1000] !

Comment: You have a typo: name of the last result is not `randRange1` but `randRange2`.

Comment: Thanks @JasomDotnet :-)

Comment: If so, we can combine both answers and make an if condition based on the range and count. If anyone can check the best value for the range and count threshold it will be perfect

Comment: I got Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array on line 5

Comment: @AdrianP. You need to initialize `$range` in the initial code snippet, which I never did for some reason; editing.

Comment: Nice solution for randRange2, but you forgot to add: $i = 0; at the start of the function.

Answer (score 6):

The idea consists to use the keys, when a value is already present in the array keys, the array size stays the same:

```
function getDistinctRandomNumbers ($nb, $min, $max) {
    if ($max - $min + 1 < $nb)
        return false; // or throw an exception

    $res = array();
    do {
        $res[mt_rand($min, $max)] = 1;
    } while (count($res) !== $nb);
    return array_keys($res); 
}
```

Pro: This way avoids the use of `in_array` and doesn't generate a huge array. So, it is fast and preserves a lot of memory.

Cons: when the rate (range/quantity) decreases, the speed decreases too (but stays correct). For a same rate, relative speed increases with the range size.*(*)*

*(*) I understand that fact since there are more free integers to select (in particular for the first steps), but if somebody has the mathematical formula that describes this behaviour, I am interested by, don't hesitate.*

Conclusion: The best "general" function seems to be a mix between this function and @Anne function that is more efficient with a little rate. This function should switch between the two ways when a certain quantity is needed and a rate (range/quantity) is reached. So the complexity/time of the test to know that, must be taken in account.

Comment: @Bell: thanks for your correction, I had indeed missed this.

Comment: This one needs the upvotes! I posted something similar when I had the thread sorted by votes. `!==$nb` is a nice performance trick. You might want to add `$nb=(int)$nb` in the first line and cast `$min` and `$max` to int as well, just to make sure.

Comment: CMIIW, but i think it can generate the same key that has been set previously, so it is unreliable and can lead to too long runtime if `$nb` value is very big and near with `$max - $min`

Comment: @HendraWD: you are wrong but in a particular way: there's no reason to use this function when for example you want 999.999 random values between 0 and 1.000.000 (it's easier to remove 2 numbers in a shuffled range). Whatever, for the values you are speaking about, I think that none of the solutions here aren't really appropriate for a basic reason: Who wants to end with an array of a million of items or more? In these cases, using a generator function and a "lazy evaluation" strategy is a more proper way.

Comment: @HendraWD: Note that I already described the phenomenon in the "cons" part of my answer and suggested a way to solve it.

Comment: I mean `mt_rand($min, $max)` can also generate the same number. While it is the same number, the loop is useless

Comment: @HendraWD: obviously, and I know that, but despite of these "useless loops" (for reasonable values), it stays very efficient.

Comment: Yes, but just imagine the condition if the `$max` and `$min` difference is big and `$nb` also big enough, there will be so much useless loops there

Comment: @HendraWD: I already answered that in my answer and in my previous comment, read them.

Comment: OK, thank you for your explanation @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: The function's performance is really depend on two indexes; `($max - $min) / $count` and smallness of the `$count` itself: it becomes really fast when they increases (as I saw in the tests, from a hundred times to a million times faster than the `shuffle()` way!), but becomes really inefficient when it decreases (sorry to say, but the performance sucks the index reaches 1).

Comment: @MAChitgarha: it isn't a real problem because when `($max - $min)/$count` decreases, all you have to do is to use the same function to select the numbers to exclude from the range. (in other words `$count = $max - $min - $count`)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Sorry, I didn't understand what you've said. However, your solution works really better than the `shuffle()` way in nearly all cases. The advantage of using this method over that one is that the performance really depends on `$count`, but using `shuffle()`, you would waste your resources because it highly depends on `$max`, even if your `$count` is less than 10. Nevertheless, thanks for posting this answer! ;)

Comment: @MAChitgarha: I mean: instead of selecting 999 random numbers in a range of 1000 numbers, select 1 number and remove it from the range.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes, actually; but I'm considering the other cases. For example, if you want to select 10^5 numbers from 10^6 numbers. Again, as I said, even in these cases, it performs really better than other methods.

Answer (score 3):

If you need 5 random numbers between 1 and 15, you should do:

```
var_dump(getRandomNumbers(1, 15, 5));

function getRandomNumbers($min, $max, $count)
{
    if ($count > (($max - $min)+1))
    {
        return false;
    }
    $values = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($values);
    return array_slice($values,0, $count);
}
```

It will return false if you specify a count value larger then the possible range of numbers.

Comment: Note, this is if you don't want all the numbers in the range represented.  If you do, then use on of the shuffle answers provided by others.

Comment: thnx for your code but the generated number depends on the size :(
Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated, it uses lots of memory !

Comment: var_dump(getRandomNumbers(1, 15, 5));  
function getRandomNumbers($min, $max, $count)  
i think something is wrong, i tried with these parameters (100,999,10);

Comment: try this var_dump(getRandomNumbers(1, 5, 4));

Comment: yup, it worked perfectly :) but can't select as your answer as your function took 9.9999999999989E-5 seconds vs 5.9999999999949E-5 seconds, GOD Bless

Comment: I think id you take it out of the function, replace var_dump with print_r and remove the error checking then it will.  :P

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate 100 numbers that are random, but each number appearing only once, a good way would be to generate an array with the numbers in order, then shuffle it.

Something like this:

```
$arr = array();

for ($i=1;$i<=101;$i++) {
    $arr[] = $i;
}

shuffle($arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Output will look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 16
    [1] => 93
    [2] => 46
    [3] => 55
    [4] => 18
    [5] => 63
    [6] => 19
    [7] => 91
    [8] => 99
    [9] => 14
    [10] => 45
    [11] => 68
    [12] => 61
    [13] => 86
    [14] => 64
    [15] => 17
    [16] => 27
    [17] => 35
    [18] => 87
    [19] => 10
    [20] => 95
    [21] => 43
    [22] => 51
    [23] => 92
    [24] => 22
    [25] => 58
    [26] => 71
    [27] => 13
    [28] => 66
    [29] => 53
    [30] => 49
    [31] => 78
    [32] => 69
    [33] => 1
    [34] => 42
    [35] => 47
    [36] => 26
    [37] => 76
    [38] => 70
    [39] => 100
    [40] => 57
    [41] => 2
    [42] => 23
    [43] => 15
    [44] => 96
    [45] => 48
    [46] => 29
    [47] => 81
    [48] => 4
    [49] => 33
    [50] => 79
    [51] => 84
    [52] => 80
    [53] => 101
    [54] => 88
    [55] => 90
    [56] => 56
    [57] => 62
    [58] => 65
    [59] => 38
    [60] => 67
    [61] => 74
    [62] => 37
    [63] => 60
    [64] => 21
    [65] => 89
    [66] => 3
    [67] => 32
    [68] => 25
    [69] => 52
    [70] => 50
    [71] => 20
    [72] => 12
    [73] => 7
    [74] => 54
    [75] => 36
    [76] => 28
    [77] => 97
    [78] => 94
    [79] => 41
    [80] => 72
    [81] => 40
    [82] => 83
    [83] => 30
    [84] => 34
    [85] => 39
    [86] => 6
    [87] => 98
    [88] => 8
    [89] => 24
    [90] => 5
    [91] => 11
    [92] => 73
    [93] => 44
    [94] => 85
    [95] => 82
    [96] => 75
    [97] => 31
    [98] => 77
    [99] => 9
    [100] => 59
)
```

Comment: thnx for your code but the generated number depends on the size :(
if i try to generate 3 number they are like 1, 3, 2 i want something like 1, 5, 15 [1-15 limit]
i really appreciate your help :|

Comment: Ah, you question wasn't particularly clear – might be worth rewriting it to make it more clear!

Answer (score 3):

You can try next code:

```
function unique_randoms($min, $max, $count) {

 $arr = array();
 while(count($arr) < $count){
      $tmp =mt_rand($min,$max);
      if(!in_array($tmp, $arr)){
         $arr[] = $tmp;
      }
 }
return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Get a random number. Is it stored in the array already? If not, store it. If so, then go get another random number and repeat.

Answer (score 2):

When creating an application where I needed to generate 30,000 unique numbers within a larger range, I was able to cut down processing time from 25 seconds to 1.5 seconds using this method.

The idea is that PHP is much faster at generating random numbers than it is at checking the existence of items in an array - that is why using a while(in_array) loop can be slow.

```
$count = 0;
$collectNumbers = [];
while ($count < 30000) {
for ($i = 0; $i < 60000; $i++) {

$rand = mt_rand(1, 100000);
$collectNumbers[] = $rand;

}
$unique = array_unique($collectNumbers);
$count = count($unique);
}

$finalArray = array_slice($unique, 0, 30000);
```

This will return 30,000 unique numbers extremely quickly. Using an iteration value that is double the amount of numbers you need to generate can increase the likelihood of unique numbers the first iteration... but regardless of how many iterations it takes, this will produce a result faster than checking your array for repeated numbers in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

This probably will solve your problem:

```
<?php print_r(array_rand(range(1,50), 5)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is probably a non issue for most but I tried to solve it.  I think I have a pretty decent solution. In case anyone else stumbles upon this issue.

```
function randomNums($gen, $trim, $low, $high)
{
    $results_to_gen = $gen;
    $low_range      = $low;
    $high_range     = $high;
    $trim_results_to= $trim;

    $items = array();
    $results = range( 1, $results_to_gen);
    $i = 1;

    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        $result = mt_rand( $low_range, $high_range);
        $items[] = $result;

    }


    $unique = array_unique( $items, SORT_NUMERIC);
    $countem = count( $unique);
    $unique_counted = $countem -$trim_results_to;

    $sum = array_slice($unique, $unique_counted);


    foreach ($sum as $key)
    {
        $output = $i++.' : '.$key.'<br>';
        echo $output;
    }

}
```

randomNums(1100, 1000 ,890000, 899999);

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```
$randnum1 = mt_rand(1,20);

$nomatch = 0;

while($nomatch == 0){

$randnum2 = mt_rand(1,20);

if($randnum2 != $randnum1){

$nomatch = 1;

}

}

$nomatch = 0;

while($nomatch == 0){

$randnum3 = mt_rand(1,20);

if(($randnum3 != $randnum1)and($randnum3 != $randnum2)){

$nomatch = 1;

}

}
```

Then you can echo the results to check

```
echo "Random numbers are " . $randnum1 . "," . $randnum2 . ", and " . $randnum3 . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

The "shuffle" method has a MAJOR FALW. When the numbers are big, shuffle 3 billion indexs will instantly CAUSE 500 error. Here comes a best solution for really big numbers.

```
function getRandomNumbers($min, $max, $total) {
    $temp_arr = array();
    while(sizeof($temp_arr) < $total) $temp_arr[rand($min, $max)] = true;
    return $temp_arr;
}
```

Say I want to get 10 unique random numbers from 1 billion to 4 billion.

```
$random_numbers = getRandomNumbers(1000000000,4000000000,10);
```

PS: Execution time: 0.027 microseconds

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this function and pass the count of number you want to generate

**Code:**

```
function randomFix($length)
{
    $random= "";

srand((double)microtime()*1000000);

$data = "AbcDE123IJKLMN67QRSTUVWXYZ";
$data .= "aBCdefghijklmn123opq45rs67tuv89wxyz";
$data .= "0FGH45OP89";

for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
{
    $random .= substr($data, (rand()%(strlen($data))), 1);
}
return $random;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to generate the unique random number is

```
<?php
     echo md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true).microtime(true));
?>
```