# How to generate unique numeric value with fixed length from given data in PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm

How to generate unique numeric value with fixed length from given data in PHP? For instance, I can have a string that contains numbers and characters and I need to generate unique numeric value with length 6. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612656/generating-unique-random-numbers-within-a-range-php

Comment: Sooo... you're looking for a hash whose result is a 6 digit number (~16 bit), instead of the typical 32/64/128/... bit hex?

Comment: @deceze, yes and the result should be repeatable with small number of collisions.

Comment: What about picking one of the hashes from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions with roughly 16bit results and doing a base conversion?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to generate a unique numeric value out of an input with any algorithm. That's the problem of converting an input into a pseudorandom output. If you have an input string of 20 characters and an output of only 6, **there will be repeated results**, because:

input of 20 characters (assuming 58 alphanumerical possibilities):

```
58^20 = 1.8559226468222606056912232424512e+35 possibilities
```

output of 6 characters (assuming 10 numerical possibilities):

```
10^6 = 1000000 possibilities
```

So, to sum up, you **won't be able to generate a unique number out of a string**. Your best chances are to use a hashing function like [md5](http://php.net/manual/es/function.md5.php) or [sha1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php). They are alphanumerical but you can always convert them into numbers. However, once you crop them to, let's say, 6 digits, their chances to be repeated increase a lot.

Comment: You just got yourself a fan for your permutations and combination skills.

Comment: Oh, ok, good to hear that. I'm pretty sure I forgot something in my calculations

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to generate a completely unique value given an arbitrary value with a limit on the number of characters unfortunately. There are an infinite number of possible values, while there are only 999999 possible values in a numeric value of length 6.

In PHP however you can do the following:

```
$list_of_numeric_values = array();

foreach ($list_of_given_values as $value)
{
     if (!in_array($value, $list_of_numeric_values))
         $list_of_numeric_values[] = $value;
}
```

After this is complete, the array then will have a unique key for each possible value you can use.

If you dont need to calculate these all at the same time you can follow a similar algorithm where instead of just "searching" the array using PHP perhaps its a SELECT on a MySQL table to see if the entry currently exists, and using the auto increment of the primary key to get your value.

Comment: There are *1,000,000* possible values in a 6 digit number... :-3

Comment: Im still living in the world of the Mesopotamians and havnt discovered zero is a number yet.....