# how to get Unique Random number in php

Tags: php

I am trying to develop a Computer Base Test (CBT) software on `PHP`.

I want it to retrieve question from `MYSQL` DATABASE randomly where I have 100 questions in the database.

But using `<?  rand(1,100); ?>` there is real assurance that it may select same question at same session.

How do I  select a unique random number in a session?

Comment: Here is a solution to your problem http://bit.ly/1n3fBbI

Comment: what you have tried so far..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating UNIQUE Random Numbers within a range - PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612656/generating-unique-random-numbers-within-a-range-php)

Comment: make array of selected random numbers, compare next time whether it is already selected or not

Comment: @AyazShah. I HAVE TRIED rand() BUT IT IS RETRIEVING 2 QUESTION AT SAME SESSION

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RAND()` to get random questions from database. And to take-care of uniqueness of questions you can use `IN` keyword while selecting new question from database. Means you need to keep track of all old Questions to check `IN`.

OR you can get all unique questions from database using `RAND()` at once and use those questions for that session.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this solves your problem with `php`. But with [Mysql rand()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-rand-function.php) you can retrieve random questions from db.

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY RAND();
```

If you want 10 random rows out of 100 rows

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: DO YOU MEAN IT WILL SELECT RANDOM QUESTION NUMBER WITHOUT REPEATING SAME QUESTION TWICE ?