# How to make an automatic code generator in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to make an automatic code generator so that I can send it to a                           mobile using my API then verify it after checking in php `codeigniter`
My one related controller looks like:

```
 public function print_patientdetails($id,$veri,$phone,$username) {

     if($veri == 0){
         $verifycode = "12345";   // here I need an automatic code generator function
         $result['verifycode'] = "12345";//and here need to  keep the code and pass hidden throughout the pages 
         echo $this->sendverifymsg($phone, $verifycode);
         $result['query'] = $this->panel_model->hospitaldetails($sess_id);
         $result['query1'] = $this->register_model->view_register($phone, $username);

         $this->load->view('innerheader', $result);
         $this->load->view('verify', $result);
         $this->load->view('footer', $result); 
    }else{
        $sess_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $result['query'] = $this->panel_model->hospitaldetails($sess_id);
        $result['query1'] = $this->register_model->edit_patient($id);
        foreach ($result['query1'] as $row)
        {
            $phone = $row->phone;
            $username = $row->userid;
            $email = $row->email;

            $this->load->view('print_patientdetail', $result);
            echo $this->sendregistermsg($phone, $username);
            echo $this->mail($email, $phone, $username); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain yourself again? what do you man with codegenerator?

Comment: Do you mean a cron job?

Comment: check [this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612656/generating-unique-random-numbers-within-a-range-php), it will give you random number generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i understood is you just need something which can generate a random code for you.
if this is purpose you can use `rand(0,99999);` function which generates random numbers.

Moreover if you need that this random number should not b one from already generated then you can use db to store random numbers, enter it when it generates and at the time of new generating compare it with already stored random numbers.

Comment: ...ya i need something which can generate a random code.

Comment: its not a problem if its already generated. but using rand (0,99999) how can generated a code in above variable "$verifycode"..can u please explain a littel bit..

Comment: you welcome dear, this answer has not worked for you? you accepted and then unaccepted it ?

Comment: no problem its okay, actually the rule is accept that answer which best and fullfill your requirement because it will also helpfull for other users who will visit it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use php `uniqid()` native function like this:

```
$verifycode = uniqid();
```