# PHP display random n images from directory

Tags: php, html

I want to display random n number of images from a folder. Currently i am using this script to display images

```
<?php
$dir = './images/gallery/';
foreach(glob($dir.'*.jpg') as $file) { ?>
<div class="item"><img src="<?php=$file;?>"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

I want only 10 (or n number) images, that too randomly. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shuffle()` method will put the elements of a given array in a random order:

```
<?php
$dir = './images/gallery/';

function displayImgs($dir, $n=10){
$files = glob($dir.'*.jpg');
shuffle($files);
$files = array_slice($files, 0, $n);
foreach($files as $file) { ?>
<div class="item"><img src="<?php=$file;?>"></div>
<?php } 
} ?>
```

**Usage:** 
displayImgs("/dir/temp/path", 20);

Comment: I am not sure if this is going to display random images

Comment: n is default equal to 10 in this function. If you have 10 images in an array then you will address them as 0 through 9 or (10-1) here

Comment: I know that @TravisConnelly , just ensuring Jitendra posts a well-rounded answer, not leaving much speculation from the OP ;-)

Comment: @JitendraKumar.Balla I am getting error `Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in...`

Comment: @user3045457, Updated code, shuffle() will return boolean. so that is the small mistake.

Comment: @JitendraKumar.Balla your script working fine. But here is a issue., I have 30 images in folder. If  i set $n to 10, it shows 20 images. Here the $n subtracts $n from total images and shows remaning images

Comment: @user3045457, Yes your right, I am passing $n so from that it will get all the element's from $n to array length, So if your passing one more arg, then it will works fine, array_slice($files, 0, $n); And its very simple to use , Updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this might be overkill, but you can also use a directory iterator and some randomness to achieve this. I used a modified version of the random numbers generation function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5612704/576767) answer.

make sure that the path you give to the function is relative to the directory in which the script resides, *with* a slash at the beginning. The [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constants will not change would you happen to call this script from different places in your file hierarchy.

```
<?php

function randomImages($path,$n) {

    $dir = new DirectoryIterator(__DIR__. $path);

    // we need to know how many images we can range on
    // but we do not want the two special files . and ..
    $count = iterator_count($dir) - 2;

    // slightly modified function to create an array containing n random position
    // within our range
    $positionsArray = UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(0,$count-1,$n);

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($dir as $file) {

        // those super files seldom make good images
        if ($file->getFilename() === '.' || $file->getFilename() === '..') continue;

        if (isset($positionsArray[$i])) echo '<div class="item"><img src="'.$file->getPathname().'"></div>';

        $i++;
        // change the count after the check of the filename,
        // because otherwise you might overflow
    }
}

function UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    return array_flip(array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity));
}
```

Comment: Super. Works fine. But, my inspect-element shows `<img src="./images/gallery\images-room.jpg">`. Why it shows \ instead /?

Comment: hmmm... not sure. you on a windows box? does it display correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Let us first create a array and push some random numbers into it. And as per you let `$n` be `10`.

```
$n = 10;
$arr = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++){
    /* Where $n is the limit */
    $rand = rand($n);
    array_push($arr, $rand);
}
```

So now we have an array containing the random digits and now we have to echo out the images by iterating over the array:

```
foreach($arr as $image){
    $intToStr = (string) $image;
    foreach(glob($dir. $intToStr . '.jpg') as $file){
        echo "<div class='item'>$file</div>";
    }
}
```

This would echo out your images.

Comment: Simply you can use shuffle()