# Generate a given number of random numbers with given constraints (PHP)?

Tags: php

I would like to generate a given number of random numbers with given constraints.
Here, I would like the difference between every other element to be at least (say) 3 and the (generated) number to fall within a given range.

I have found a function to generate a given number of random numbers  in a given range ([Generating UNIQUE Random Numbers within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612656/generating-unique-random-numbers-within-a-range)):

```
function UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
}
print_r( UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(0,25,5) );
```

which gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20
    [1] => 23
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 18
    [4] => 17
)
```

and does not meet the requirements.
Instead

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20
    [1] => 24
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 12
    [4] => 8
)
```

would work.

Is there a simple way to do that in PHP ?

Best,

Comment: Do you still want to use a range?

Comment: Yes :-) I Edit the question

Comment: @chac1 You can run out of numbers if the range is less for a diff. to be at least 3

Comment: @chac1 _only the third element (7) satisfies the constraint (difference larger than 3)_ but difference with respect to what?

Comment: @nice_dev As I understood it, neighbouring elements.

Comment: @El_Vanja (17,23) is also a good pair. I presume with every other element?

Comment: Yes. Every other element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Generate a random seed value between `$min` and `$max`.
- Collect all numbers less than $seed which has differences greater than or equal to `$min_diff`(say 3). Stop at $min.
- Collect all numbers greater than $seed which has differences greater than or equal to `$min_diff`(say 3). Stop at $max.
- Shuffle the numbers.
- Return the `array_slice()` with the required quantity.
- If constraint cannot be fulfilled, throw an exception.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange($min, $max, $quantity ,$min_diff = 3) {
    $rand_seed = rand($min,$max);
    $numbers = [];
    $curr = $rand_seed;
    while($curr >= $min){
        $numbers[] = $curr;
        $curr -= $min_diff;
    }
    
    $curr = $rand_seed;
    while($curr <= $max){
        $curr += $min_diff;
        if($curr <= $max) $numbers[] = $curr;
    }
    shuffle($numbers);
    if(count($numbers) < $quantity){
        throw new Exception("Constraints cannot be fulfilled with given quantity: $quantity and given min. diff.:$min_diff");
    }
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
}

print_r( UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(0,25,5) );
```